# Finding SSL issuer for a domain with Firefox

Tags: ssl, firefox-addon

i bought ssl certificates from a budget issuer and have lost track of who they are.

is there a method of clearing all certs from firefox, recollecting the certificate, and see a window with the domain name next to the issuer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Viewing the certificate allows you to view the entire chain.  You do not need to clear the certs from firefox to do this.  Click the blue part of the url bar on the right, then 'more information', 'view certificate', 'details' tab.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your certificate then it may still be in the certificate manager.